# Create Connectable WebParts with html and JS

Tags: javascript, web-part, connected-web-parts

With C# it s possible to create Webparts with Connection Provider and Connection Consumer. So you can exchange data between 2 Webparts on a page. 
Is this also possible with html and javascript?

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to connect to web services is to use the Codeplex project [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) which is (free to use and) entirely client side.

> **Project Description**
>   SPServices is a jQuery library which abstracts SharePoint's Web
>   Services and makes them easier to use. It also includes functions
>   which use the various Web Service operations to provide more useful
>   (and cool) capabilities. It works entirely client side and requires no
>   server install.

Comment: Since SPServices is an (old) SOAP library originating from SP2007 days and the future (is now) is REST, I would look at the PnP Core JS Libary Microsoft built (with the community) https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core  It is more in line with current Microsoft SPFx SharePoint Framework developments, note: PnPJS is **not** tied to SPFx, so you can use it in any REST scenario

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman That's right! You should add that as an answer and you'll get my upvote! :)

Comment: Its not an answer to his question, actually no REST answer is. INpage  JavaScript can let WebParts communicate to each other, all that C# stuff is just complex Postback stuff from ye'old days when Microsoft didn't use modern webstandards... (oh.. that was last year :-)

Answer (score 0):

for  a backend (c#) you can if you need it. Its on msdn:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms469765(v=office.14).aspx

goes through:

"Creating an Interface", "Creating a Provider Web Part" and "Creating a Consumer Web Part"

the most important part is "ConnectionProviderAttribute Class" as its used in the provider and consumer class. Below is a more in-depth info on the class with another example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/s200ex30